# Get-AzApiManagementSubscription command returns the subscription list but the keys values are empty

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-powershell, azure-api-management

When i'm running in my machine the commands

```
$apimContext = New-AzApiManagementContext -ResourceGroupName "xxxxxxxxxxxxx" -ServiceName "xxxxxxxxx"

Get-AzApiManagementProduct -Context $apimContext -ProductId "xxxxxxxxx"

Get-AzApiManagementSubscription -Context $apimContext -ProductId "xxxxxxxxx"
```

The result is a subscription object with empty keys

```
SubscriptionId    : xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
UserId            : 1
OwnerId           : /subscriptions/xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx/resourceGroups/xxxx 
                    xxxx/providers/Microsoft.ApiManagement/service/xxxxx 
                    xxxxx/users/1
ProductId         : xxxxxx
Scope             : /subscriptions/xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx/resourceGroups/xxxx 
                    xxxx/providers/Microsoft.ApiManagement/service/xxxxx 
                    xxxx/products/xxxxxx
Name              : 
State             : Active
CreatedDate       : 29/04/2022 15:03:33
StartDate         : 29/04/2022 00:00:00
ExpirationDate    : 
EndDate           : 
NotificationDate  : 
PrimaryKey        : 
SecondaryKey      : 
StateComment      : 
AllowTracing      : True
Id                : /subscriptions/xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx/resourceGroups/xxxxx 
                    xxxxx/providers/Microsoft.ApiManagement/service/xxxxx 
                    xxxx/products/xxxxxx/subscriptions/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx   
ResourceGroupName : xxxxxxxxxxxxxx
ServiceName       : xxxxxxxxxxx
```

As we can see the keys appear empty, but in the documentation examples it provides values. If i go to azure portal with my account i can see the values

[image]

Is there something i can do when running in a personal machine or in an azure pipeline so that i can get the key values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code result examples conflict with the documentation for [Get-AzApiManagementSubscription](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.apimanagement/get-azapimanagementsubscription?view=azps-7.5.0#description)

> The Get-AzApiManagementSubscription cmdlet gets a specified
> subscription, or all subscriptions, if no subscription is specified.
> **Keys will not be included into result details. To get keys, use
> Get-AzApiManagementSubscriptionKey**.

See [Get-AzApiManagementSubscriptionKey](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.apimanagement/get-azapimanagementsubscriptionkey?view=azps-7.5.0)

Comment: Thanks so much since the names of the commands are so similar and since i clearly didn't read well that part i was thinking i was doing something wrong. It's strange that it has a primary and secondary key in the result but then it doesn't provide values.

Comment: Seems that prior to version 2.0.0 of the module, the cmdlet did indeed return the keys, and the documentation wasn't updated. I've submitted a pull request to update the examples